# G=S_3 (symmetry group), H=\langle(123) \rangle , K=$\langle$(12)$\rangle$. Why G is said not isomorphic to external direct product of H and K?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\phi $ be function from G to H $\oplus$ K such that $\phi$ (123)=((123),(1)), $\phi$ (132)=((13)(1)) and etc. I has checking some case like $\phi$((123)(132))=$\phi$(123).$\phi$(132) and etc. Its look that there are isomorphism from G to  H $\oplus$ K, but the book said the otherwise. Where is my fault?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken (I could be, this is hard to read... you could have made an effort to format your question with TeX), you have not defined psi on all G, only on H.

Comment: The direct product of two abelian groups is abelian. $S_3$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But yesterday i have an  reasoning that i think easier to understand, maybe. S3 is not cyclic but ex. Dp of H and K are cyclic. The order of generator, say a, exdp of H, K is equal with the order of exdp H, K. Then, a^6=e, a^1*a^5 = e, etc. So, by observing, we cant make bijective function from exdp H, K to G.

Comment: Im sorry, im new in this site, so i cant write the symbols in proper form yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed $\psi$ is not a homomorphism, since the order of $(13)$ in $S_3$ is $2$, but $\psi((13))$ must be either $((123), (12))$ or $((132), (12))$, which both have an order of $6$ in $\langle (123) \rangle \oplus \langle (12) \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But yesterday i have an reasoning that i think easier to understand, maybe. S3 is not cyclic but ex. Dp of H and K are cyclic. The order of generator, say a, exdp of H, K is equal with the order of exdp H, K. Then, a^6=e, a^1*a^5 = e, etc. So, by observing, we cant make bijective function from exdp H, K to G.